# Auto layout - complex constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to display content in a table cell using auto layout, programmatically. I'd like for the content to display as follows:

[title]
[image] [date]
[long string of text, spanning the width of the table, maximum of two lines]

My code looks like this:

```
-(NSArray *)constraints {
    NSMutableArray * constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_titleLabel, _descriptionLabel, _dateLabel, _ratingBubbleView);

    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding":@(kPadding)};

    NSString *const kVertical = @"V:|-(>=0,<=padding)-[_titleLabel]-(<=padding)-[_ratingBubbleView]-(<=padding)-[_descriptionLabel]-(>=0,<=padding)-|";
    NSString *const kVertical2 = @"V:|-(>=0,<=padding)-[_titleLabel]-(<=padding)-[_dateLabel]-(<=padding)-[_descriptionLabel]-(>=0,<=padding)-|";
    NSString *const kHorizontalDescriptionLabel = @"H:|-padding-[_descriptionLabel]-padding-|";
    NSString *const kHorizontalTitleLabel = @"H:|-padding-[_titleLabel]";
    NSString *const kHorizontalDateLabel = @"H:|-padding-[_ratingBubbleView]-padding-[_dateLabel]";

    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kVertical options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kVertical2 options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kHorizontalDescriptionLabel options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kHorizontalTitleLabel options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kHorizontalDateLabel options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];

    return constraints;
}
```

This is the result:
[image: This is the result]

Comment: Why the `(>=0, <=padding)`? Could you possibly add a picture (or sketch) of the layout you are trying to achieve? It's quite hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish just from looking at the constraints. Also, what is not correct about the display? You said it isn't correct but you haven't said what it actually is doing.

Comment: What result did this code give you? Be specific, "image and date aren't displaying correctly" isn't useful for those trying to help you.

Comment: @Fogmeister I updated the question to show what I mean. Thanks for pointing that out. As for the `(>=0, <=padding)`, I'm still very new to objective-c and autolayout, and this was put in by the previous developer working on this project.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm not going to try a fix your code. I'm just going to create constraints that I would use to achieve your layout. I'll put the thought process in comments.

**First get a nice vertical layout going...**

```
// I'm just using standard padding to make it easier to read.
// Also, I'd avoid the variable padding stuff. Just set it to a fixed value.
// i.e. ==padding not (>=0, <=padding). That's confusing to read and ambiguous.
@"V:|-[titleLabel]-[ratingBubbleView]-[descriptionLabel]-|"
```

**Then go through layer by layer adding horizontal constraints...**

```
// constraint the trailing edge too. You never know if you'll get a stupidly
// long title. You want to stop it colliding with the end of the screen.
// use >= here. The label will try to take it's intrinsic content size
// i.e. the smallest size to fit the text. Until it can't and then it will
// break it's content size to keep your >= constraint.
@"|-[titleLabel]->=20-|"

// when adding this you need the option "NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom".
@"|-[ratingBubbleView]-[dateLabel]->=20-|"

@"|-[descriptionLabel]-|"
```

Try not to "over constrain" your view. In your code you are constraining the same views with multiple constraints (like descriptionLabel to the bottom of the superview).

Once they're defined they don't need to be defined again.

Again, with the padding. Just use `padding` rather than `>=padding`. Does >=20 mean 20, 21.5, or 320? The inequality is ambiguous when laying out.

Also, In my constraints I have used the layout option to constrain the vertical axis of the date label to the rating view. i.e. "Stay in line vertically with the rating view". Instead of constraining against the title label and stuff... This means I only need to define the position of that line of UI once.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. It's tough to find a good tutorial on this topic.

Comment: @Matt agreed. The best (by a long way) that I found was Ray Wenderlich's book **iOS7 by Tutorials**. Two whole chapters on AutoLayout. There is now an **iOS8 by Tutorials** too. Definitely worth buying.

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately, these new constraints are breaking the display even worse: [This is the result](http://i.imgur.com/h8P7mz2.png)

Comment: @Matt Can you show some more code? Also, you'll need to remove all the constraints you currently have. Any chance of creating a gist I can take a look at? The constraints I put shouldn't look like that.

Comment: @Matt can you gist that entire file. Just so I can see what's going on and what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. It's been awhile since I had to use SO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61848/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-matt).

Comment: You may need to make sure the superview has enough space for itself. From the second picture here, it looks like it has enough space.

You probably need to add one additional constraint that @Fogmeister didn't add which is to keep the Y center of the imageView and the date the same (so that they align vertically) - otherwise the dateLabel has no constraint for how to align vertically.

Comment: @MikeWelsh I specified to add that as an option when adding the constraints using VFL. Updated in the gist. Actually, I used `bottom` but it would have the same (ish) effect.

Comment: My mistake, missed the last sentence!

Comment: @MikeWelsh no worries :) this is a bizarre one. Join us in chat if you want. Trying to work out what's not working with this.